# Popup boxes show up at the beginning, but should be hidden

Tags: javascript, html, popup, hide

I am trying to write a short html / javascript that shows popup boxes that I defined. IMPORTANT: They should not show up at the beginning.

However, they are also shown at the beginning (and not hidden). Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here the code:

```
  <script>

       $(document).ready(function(){
         setTimeout(function(event){               // Öffnet 1.Box nach x Sekungen
                loadPopupBox(); -maxSpeed/0.1
            }, 7000);


         $("#popupclose").click(function(event){
            unloadPopupBox();                     // Schliesst 1. Box mit Click
            setTimeout(function(event2) {          // Öffnet 2. Box nach x Sekunden
                  loadPopupBox2(); -maxSpeed/0.1
                 }, 500);

            setTimeout(function(event2) {          // Schliesst 2. Box nach x Sekunden
              unloadPopupBox2()
              }, 3500);

            setTimeout(function(event3){
                  loadPopupBox3(); -maxSpeed/0.1         //Öffnet 3. Box nach x Sekunden
            }, 15000);

          });

         $("#popupclose3").click(function(event4)
         {
            unloadPopupBox3();
            setTimeout(function(event4) {
                  loadPopupBox4(); -maxSpeed/0.1}, 500);
           setTimeout(function(event4) {          // Schliesst 4. Box nach x Sekunden
                  unloadPopupBox4()}, 3500);
            setTimeout(function(event5) {
                 loadPopupBox5(); -maxSpeed/0.1 }, 15000);

            });


         $("#popupclose5").click(function(event6)
         {
            unloadPopupBox5();
            setTimeout(function() { loadPopupBox6(); -maxSpeed/0.1}, 500);
             setTimeout(function(event6) {          // Schliesst 5. Box nach x Sekunden
                  unloadPopupBox6()}, 4500);
            });

         function loadPopupBox()
         {
            $("#popupbox").fadeIn("slow");
         }

         function loadPopupBox2()
         {
            $("#popupbox2").fadeIn("slow");
         }

         function loadPopupBox3()
         {
            $("#popupbox3").fadeIn("slow");
         }

         function loadPopupBox4()
         {
            $("#popupbox4").fadeIn("slow");
         }

         function loadPopupBox5()
         {
            $("#popupbox5").fadeIn("slow");
         }

         function loadPopupBox6()
         {
            $("#popupbox6").fadeIn("slow");
         }


         function unloadPopupBox()
         {
            $("#popupbox").fadeOut("normal");
         }

         function unloadPopupBox2()
         {
            $("#popupbox2").fadeOut("normal");
         }

         function unloadPopupBox3()
         {
            $("#popupbox3").fadeOut("normal");
         }

         function unloadPopupBox4()
         {
            $("#popupbox4").fadeOut("normal");
         }

         function unloadPopupBox5()
         {
            $("#popupbox5").fadeOut("normal");
         }

         function unloadPopupBox6()
         {
            $("#popupbox6").fadeOut("normal");
         }
         $("#popupbox").hide();
         $("#popupbox2").hide();
         $("#popupbox3").hide();
         $("#popupbox4").hide();
         $("#popupbox5").hide();
         $("#popupbox6").hide();
       });

    </script>

    <style>
           #wings { margin-top:100px; margin-left:150px; font:bold 13px sans-serif; background:orange;
                    float:left; padding:6px; }

           #popupbox { position:fixed; _position:absolute; /*hack for IE6*/ background:#81DAF5;
                       top:170px; border:2px solid lightblue; padding:15px; z-index:100px;opacity: .8;
                       font-size:15px; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px lightgray; -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightblue;
                       box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightblue; }

           #popupclose { border:0px solid lightgray; color:#33CC33; font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:bold;
                         line-height:15px; float:left; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none; }

           #popupbox2 { position:fixed; _position:absolute; /*hack for IE6*/ background:#81DAF5;
                       top:190px; border:2px solid lightblue; padding:15px; z-index:100px;opacity: .8;
                       font-size:15px; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px lightgray; -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightblue;
                       box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightblue; }

           #popupclose2 { border:0px solid lightgray; color:#33CC33; font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:bold;
                         line-height:15px; float:left; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none; }

           #popupbox3 { position:fixed; _position:absolute; /*hack for IE6*/ background:#81DAF5;
                       top:175px; border:2px solid lightblue; padding:15px; z-index:100px;opacity: .8;
                       font-size:15px; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px lightgray; -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightblue;
                       box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightblue; }

           #popupclose3 { border:0px solid lightgray; color:#33CC33; font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:bold;
                         line-height:15px; float:left; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none; }

           #popupbox4 { position:fixed; _position:absolute; /*hack for IE6*/ background:#81DAF5;
                       top:165px; border:2px solid lightblue; padding:15px; z-index:100px;opacity: .8;
                       font-size:15px; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px lightgray; -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightblue;
                       box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightblue; }

           #popupclose4 { border:0px solid lightgray; color:#33CC33; font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:bold;
                         line-height:15px; float:left; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none; }

           #popupbox5 { position:fixed; _position:absolute; /*hack for IE6*/ background:#81DAF5;
                       top:200px; border:2px solid lightblue; padding:15px; z-index:100px;opacity: .8;
                       font-size:15px; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px lightgray; -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightblue;
                       box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightblue; }

           #popupclose5 { border:0px solid lightgray; color:#33CC33; font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:bold;
                         line-height:15px; float:left; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none; }


           #popupbox6 { position:fixed; _position:absolute; /*hack for IE6*/ background:#81DAF5;
                       top:150px; border:2px solid lightblue; padding:15px; z-index:100px;opacity: .8;
                       font-size:15px; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px lightgray; -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightblue;
                       box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightblue; }

           #popupclose6 { border:0px solid lightgray; color:#33CC33; font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:bold;
                         line-height:15px; float:left; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none; }
    </style>



             <div id="popupbox">
               <div style="height:75px; margin-left: 70px"><img id="popupclose" src="images/Picturenavigation.png" width="300" height="150" alt="Picturenavigation" title="Picturenavigation" border="0"></div>
              </br></br>
                   <table>
              </br></br></br>
                        <tr><td><center>Picturebook Navigation uses the coordinates of photos to navigate. </center></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><b><center>Click on the picture to start your journey.</center></b></td></tr>

                   </table>
                 </div>

             <div id="popupbox2">
               <div style="height:120px; margin-left: 60px"><img id="popupclose2" src="images/Naviroute3.jpg" width="300" height="150" alt="Naviroute3" title="Naviroute3" border="0"></div>
                     <table>
                          </br> </br>
                          <tr><td><center>Navigation with connect is that easy: You are on your way now!</center></td></tr>
                     </table>
                   </div>

             <div id="popupbox3">
              <div style="height:120px; margin-left:90px;"><img id="popupclose3" src="images/Connect_Menu.jpg" width="300" height="150" alt="Connect_Menu" title="Connect_Menu" border="0"></div>
                    <table>
                         </br></br>
                         <tr><td>Have you ever wondered about the latest news on your favorite team </br>or what the weather will look like at your travel destination?</td></tr>
                         <tr><td><b>Click on the connect menu to continue your drive and stay informed.</b></td></tr>

                    </table>
                   </div>

               <div id="popupbox4">
               <div style="height:120px; margin-left:60px;"><img id="popupclose4" src="images/Weather.jpg" width="300" height="150" alt="Weather" title="Weather" border="0"></div>
                </br>
                     <table>
                          </br></br>
                          <tr><td><center>The weather is going to be nice tomorrow: No need for an umbrella.</center></td></tr>
                     </table>
                   </div>


               <div id="popupbox5">
               <div style="height:60px;"><img id="popupclose5" src="images/Bild1.png" width="80" height="76" alt="Bild1" title="Bild1" border="0"style="float:right;"></div>
                </br>
                     <table>
                          <tr><td>Send a friend a message: <i>"Hi, it's me. I am on the way." </i></td></tr>
                          <tr><td></tr></td>
                          <tr><td>Type in this phone number in the space below: +1425637089.</td></tr>
                          <tr><td>Phone Number : <input type="text" size="30%"></td></tr>
                          <tr><td><b>Click on the picture to send the message.</b></td></tr>
                     </table>
                   </div>

   <div id="popupbox6">
               <div style="height:180px; margin-left:155px;"><img id="popupclose6" src="images/Message_received.png" width="125" height="190" alt="Message Received" title="Message Received" border="0"></div>
                     <table>
                         </br>
                          <tr><td>Look how easy this was! Your message already has been received.</td></tr>
                     </table>
                   </div>
```

Comment: Use `display:none` for the elements you want to hide.

Comment: Oh god... "minimum code necessary to duplicate the issue"

Comment: Wo ist ihre css? Wir brauchen das... und ihre html. Sie sollen ein JSFiddle machen.

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation would be to work on formatting your code a little more cleanly.  It's much easier to find mistakes when everything is readable.  In addition, your js contains a lot of repeat code, and is probably why this question is so heavily downvoted.

To the actual answer, you never actually hide your pop up boxes.  In the css, you need to set #popupbox1 { display: none; } for each box on the page.  Even better would be to use a class, but you don't really have that set up here.

Comment: Hi, it worked, but now the popup boxes do not show up anymore (e.g., after couple of seconds, as intended). I used:  <style media="screen" type="text/css">

#popupbox { display: none; }



</style>
<css>

Comment: Probably because you're using fadeIn('slow').  Swap it with show(1500) and it should work.